# How do I download text data as json with a download button in typescript react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript

I am trying to learn to use react and typescript. However, I am really stuck here.

I am trying to download the text data from a card using a download button in json format. So far my code looks like this:

App.tsx

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import Tooltip from "@material-ui/core/Tooltip";
export const MyCard = () => {
const classes = useStyles();

return (
<Card className={classes.root}>
     <CardHeader
            title="My React Typescript App"
            subheader="Aug 16, 2021"
        />
     <IconButton>
     <Tooltip title={"Download content"}>
     </Tooltip>
     </IconButton>
</Card>
```

);

I want to be able to download the title and subheader in json format when I click on the button. How can I do that?

Comment: not that this will break the code, but should'nt `IconButton` be inside of `Tooltip`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use below function to download JSON.

```
    const Demo = () => {
  const [cardTitle, setCardTitle] = useState('My React Typescript App');
  const [cardSubTitle, setCardSubTitle] = useState('Aug 16, 2021');

  const DownloadJSON = Data => {
    const dataStr =
      'data:application/json;charset=utf-8,' +
      encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(Data));
    const download = document.createElement('a');
    download.setAttribute('href', dataStr);
    download.setAttribute('download', 'CardData' + '.json');
    document.body.appendChild(download);
    download.click();
    download.remove();
  };
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader title={cardTitle} subheader={cardSubTitle} />
      <Tooltip title="Delete">
        <IconButton
          aria-label="delete"
          onClick={() => {
            DownloadJSON({ cardTitle, cardSubTitle });
          }}
        >
          Download content
        </IconButton>
      </Tooltip>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Comment: pls use `const` instead of `var`

Comment: @Hardik Thanks for your answer. It's gradually making sense to me. However, I get a "Parameter 'Data' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7006" error. Do you know how I can debug it?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to resolve it. Thanks a lot! This makes so much sense now.